# pandas string data types

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to specify data types for pandas read_csv. Here's a quick look at something that does work and then doesn't when types are specified. Why doesn't the latter work?

```
import io
import pandas as pd

csv = """foo,1234567,a,1 
foo,2345678,b,3 
bar,3456789,b,5 
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv),
        names=["fb", "num", "loc", "x"])

print(df)

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv),
        names=["fb", "num", "loc", "x"], 
        dtype=["|S3", "np.int64", "|S1", "np.int8"])

print(df)
```

I've updated to make this much simpler and, hopefully, clearer on BrenBarn's suggestion.  My real dataset is much larger, but I'd like to use the method to generate types for all my data on import.

Comment: Have you tried making a simpler dataset and trying with just one or two datatypes to see which one is causing the problem?

Comment: I'll do that, though the error it throws now suggests (to my novice mind) that I'm not specifying correctly, not that there is a mismatch between my specification and the data. But I'll give it a shot and report back!

Comment: pandas will convert a specified string dtype, like ``S20`` to ``object`` dtype which represents string types. Why is that a problem? This is the standard way of representing variable length strings (and is actually more efficient than a fixed ``S20`` dtype)

Comment: @Jeff Oh, cool.  So if `object` is more efficient than `string_` types, then I'm happy with that piece.  I'd like to specify all  my integer types at `int32` or less rather than `int64`, though. I guess I can try converting them post-import.

Comment: you can either do that or specifiy specific columns (but seeing as you have so many can prob just do it after).

Comment: @Jeff When I convert after import, I use the "np." prefix, but I'm still getting errors when I try to specify during import. I would like to learn how to do that if possible: can I specify `object` and `int32` dtypes in a csv import?  Do I use `dtypes = ('object', 'int32', etc.)` or do I use some other syntax like `dtypes = ('str', 'np.int32', etc.)`?  It seems like whatever I try, I still get `TypeError: data type not understood`

Comment: see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#specifying-column-data-types), basically ``dtype = { 'column_1' : np.int32, 'column_2' : np.int64 }``. You don't need to specify object as that will happen automatically for string-like columns

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38296/discussion-between-don-and-jeff)

Comment: @BrenBarn I simplified the code as you suggested.  Curious what you make of it. Do you know of any way to specify a non-numeric column (string, text, object, etc.) in pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jeff indicated, my syntax was bad.  The names and types have to be zipped into a dic style list of relationships. The code below works, but note that you can't dtype a string width; you can only define it as an object.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

csv = """foo,1234567,a,1
foo,2345678,b,3
bar,3456789,b,5
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv),
        names = ["fb", "num", "ab", "x"], 
        dtype = {"fb" : object, "num" : np.int64, "ab" : object, "x" : np.int8})
print(df)
```

Comment: Right, that's why I was asking about the simplification.  I was thinking that if you tried to simplify it down you would maybe find it out it didn't work at all, even for numeric types (although I didn't know for sure).  It still seems lame that you can't specify actual string dtype though.

Comment: pandas doesn't support the internal string types (in fact they are always converted to object).