# dataframe to dictionary:python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

So, i have a file

```
F1.txt

CDUS,CBSCS,CTRS,CTRS_ID
0,0,0.000000000375,056572
0,0,4.0746,0309044
0,0,0.6182,0971094
0,0,15.4834,075614
```

I want to insert the column names and its dtype into a dictionary with the column names being the key and the corresponding dtype of the column being the value.

My read statement has to be like this:

```
csv=pandas.read_csv('F2.txt',dtype={'CTRS_ID':str})
```

I'm expecting something like this:

```
data = {'CDUS':'int64','CBSCS':'int64','CTRS':'float64','CTRS_ID':'str'}
```

Can someone help me with this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [dtypes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html) to find the type of each column and then transform the result to a dictionary with [to_dict](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html). Also, if you want a string representation of the type, you can convert the dtypes output to string:

```
csv=pandas.read_csv('F2.txt',dtype={'CTRS_ID':str})
csv.dtypes.astype(str).to_dict()
```

Which gives the output:

```
{'CBSCS': 'int64', 'CDUS': 'int64', 'CTRS': 'float64', 'CTRS_ID': 'object'}
```

This is actually the right result, since pandas treats string as object.
I have not enough expertise to elaborate on this, but here a couple of references:

[pandas distinction between str and object types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34881079/pandas-distinction-between-str-and-object-types)

[pandas string data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081410/pandas-string-data-types)
"pandas doesn't support the internal string types (in fact they are always converted to object)" [from pandas maintainer @Jeff]

Comment: I like this answer - very neat and extremely simple

Comment: Its not working. Please check this code:`csv2 = pandas.read_csv('F1.txt') dict1 = csv2.dtypes.astype(str).to_dict()
print dict1`

Comment: This gives the output:`{'CTRS': 'object', 'CDUS': 'object', 'BOARD_ID': 'object', 'CBSCS': 'object'}`

Comment: I am afraid that might be something unexpected in your file. I tried to save your sample input to txt, import it using pd.read_csv and I obtained the expected output. 
I would say my solution is working (as it gives a dictionary with types of the columns), but your data don't have the type you were expecting

Comment: Ok i got the issue. I was putting `dtype=str` in my read_csv statement.

Comment: Please check my edit in the question. Can u suggest a solution?

Comment: Just to be clear: you import CTRS_ID as a string, but then you want to convert it to int? (One effect of this would be losing the leading zero, for example)

Comment: So Sorry that was a typo

Comment: Also to confirm, if you use my solution now you would get 'object' type for CTRS_ID, is that right?